# fail to retrieve data from firebase at datasnapshot object

Tags: android, firebase

[image]

this is my data and I want to retrieve it by using addValueEventListener but my app unfortunately stop

```
 @Override
    public void onStart() {
        super.onStart();

        db.addValueEventListener(new ValueEventListener() {
            @Override
            public void onDataChange(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
                List.clear();

               for(DataSnapshot dSnapshot :dataSnapshot.getChildren()){
                   List<String> td = (ArrayList<String>) dataSnapshot.getValue();
                 // data data1=dSnapshot.getValue(data.class);
                   List.add(data1);

               }

              DataList adapter =new DataList(Fragment1.this.getActivity(),List);
               list.setAdapter(adapter);
            }


            @Override
            public void onCancelled(DatabaseError databaseError) {

            }
        });


    }
```

my app is stopped due to this line of code so tell me any alternative.

```
//**data data1=dSnapshot.getValue(data.class);

 List.add(data1);)
```

Comment: post decalration of listView, List<T> and fireabase database reference  too in the project for better help

Comment: have a look at this helper class https://github.com/AtifAbbAsi19/Firebase-Helper/blob/master/app/src/main/java/inc/droidflick/firebasetutorial/firebasenetwork/FireBaseHelper.java

Answer (score 1):

Assuming that your `db` variable points out to the correct reference.

> Instead of using `ValueEventListener` and looping through each child.
>   Use `ChildEventListener` and make sure that the `DatabaseReference` is pointing to the root where the child resides, so we can iterate through each POJO.

```
db.addChildEventListener(new ChildEventListener() {
public void onChildAdded(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot, String previousKey) {
    list.add(dataSnapshot.getValue(YourModel.class)); // Change with your POJO
    // Add to your list
}
public void onChildChanged(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot, String s) {
}
public void onChildRemoved(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
}
public void onChildMoved(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot, String s) {
}
public void onCancelled(DatabaseError er) { }});
```

> If you want to retrieve Generics in Realtime Database use
>   Firebase's abstract class [GenericTypeIndicator](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/android/com/google/firebase/database/GenericTypeIndicator)

```
GenericTypeIndicator<List<Message>> t = new GenericTypeIndicator<List<Message>>() {};
 List<Message> messages = snapshot.getValue(t);
```

Answer (score 0):

```
 use this method
//-----------------// data inside kids----------

        private void getDataFrom() {

            String userId = FirebaseAuth.getInstance().getCurrentUser().getUid();

            DatabaseReference mCustomerDatabase = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference().child("users").child("kids");

            mCustomerDatabase.addListenerForSingleValueEvent(new ValueEventListener() {
                @Override
                public void onDataChange(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
                    if (dataSnapshot.exists() && dataSnapshot.getChildrenCount() > 0) {
                        Map<String, Object> map = (Map<String, Object>) dataSnapshot.getValue();
                        if (map.get("kid1ID") != null) {
                            customer_name = map.get("title").toString();
                            Log.i("kid1ID",String.valueOf(kid1ID));

                        }

                    }
                }

                @Override
                public void onCancelled(DatabaseError databaseError) {
                }
            });
        }
```

Comment: Please correct  (according to your requirement ) path :-  DatabaseReference mCustomerDatabase = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference().child("users").child("kids");

Comment: i want to store the data in listView